# lagging display in SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, macos

I'm creating a java GUI using SWT. I'm currently running it on a Mac. The process that the GUI is a front for takes some time to run (approx. 70 minutes). Once I start this long process through the GUI, I get the rainbow spinning wheel and the GUI hangs until the process is complete. Is there any way I can solve this? Would it involve starting the process on a different thread?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must **never** run things that take a long time in the SWT user interface thread. It is essential that the SWT `readAndDispatch` method is called frequently.

So, yes, you must a background thread for any long running code.

Note that code running in a background thread cannot access UI controls directly. You must use the `Display.asyncExec` or `Display.syncExec` methods to run code that updates the UI.